# jQuery - Trigger a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

I am trying to trigger a function from a html file that is located in another function in js file. I am trying to use the `trigger` method but i cannot make it to work.
Any suggestions how to do this? [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/6u9udL99/2/)

```
<div id="result4" style="color:white; background:black">
  from function
</div>


<script>
  var TEST = new test({
    type: "image",
    file: "test.jpg",
    breakingPoint: 100
  });

  TEST.trigger('reset');

</script>
```

JS

```
function test(args) {

  $this.on('reset', function() {
    $("#result4").html("new text");
    console.log("OK");
  });

}
```

Comment: What makes you think your `TEST` object has `trigger` method? Also you don't define the `$this` variable in your code. There are several problems in your code that without knowing what you are trying to do no one can help you.

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher i get `TypeError: TEST.trigger is not a function. (In 'TEST.trigger('reset')', 'TEST.trigger' is undefined)`

Comment: @Vohuman if does not have it, how can I add a trigger method to test?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the console log, your fiddle has an error:

```
$this.on('reset', function() {
  $("#result4").html("new text");
  console.log("OK");
});
```

`$this` is not defined.

and looking at the documentation for trigger:

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

you are invoking it wrong.  You are creating your own object that does not have a `trigger` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define $this and return it as the object for test since trigger is a jquery function and not a native JavaScript Object function.

```
    function test(args) {
       var $this = $(this); // declare $this
  var default_options = {
    breakingPoint: 2000
  };

  var options = $.extend({}, default_options, args);

  $("#result1").html(options.type);
  $("#result2").html(options.file);
  $("#result3").html(options.breakingPoint);

  $this.on('reset', function() {
    $("#result4").html("new text");
    console.log("OK");
  });
  return $this; 

}

var TEST = new test({
  type: "image",
  file: "test.jpg",
  breakingPoint: 100
});

TEST.trigger('reset');
```

Comment: @SNos np. But, you were also misssing var $this = $(this).

Comment: Yes in the fiddle I have forgot it

Comment: is there a way I can send an array into the reset function?

Comment: You can't pass anything into the reset function directly. But you can declare a array in the 'test' function and it will be visible in the 'reset function.

Answer (score -1):

Wrap you  tag code in jquerys ready event. This will execute it once the DOM is loaded instead of as it is parsed.

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var TEST = test({
        type: "image",
        file: "test.jpg",
        breakingPoint: 100
    });

    TEST.reset();
});
</script>
```

In JS File

```
var test = function(options){
    var that = {};
    // you can use type, file & breaking point with option.type options.file etc..
    that.reset = function() {
        $("#result4").html("new text");
        console.log("OK");
    };

    return that;
};
```

Comment: `$(document).ready` is not a magical thing that can solve every problem.

Comment: Thank you but I still get `'TEST.trigger' is undefined`